# Check if the difference between dates is exactly 'n' months in expression SSRS

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

In my quarterly report Im trying to validate the two parameters `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
I first check if the difference between the dates is 2 months:

```
Switch(DateDiff(
DateInterval.Month, Parameters!StartDate.Value, Parameters!EndDate.Value) <> 2, 
"Error message")
```

Then I try to add whether the `StartDate` is the first day of month AND `EndDate` is last day of month:

```
And (Day(Parameters!StartDate.Value) <> 1 
And Day(DATEADD(DateInterval.Day,1,Parameters!EndDate.Value)))
```

So the whole expression looks like this:

```
Switch(DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Parameters!StartDate.Value, Parameters!EndDate.Value) <> 2  
And 
Parameters!IsQuarterly.Value = true 
And 
Day(Parameters!StartDate.Value) <> 1 
And
Day(DATEADD(DateInterval.Day,1,Parameters!EndDate.Value))<>1),
"Error: Quarterly report must include 3 months")
```

But It works wrong when the difference between dates is still 2 months, but `StartDate` and `EndDate` are not first and last day of the whole period.

I'd appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say just change the implementation Add another two Parameter With Quarter and Year 
Quarter like Q1,Q2,Q3 & Q4 with Value 1,2,3 & 4 respectively and year 2012,2013,2014 & so on

Now based on the parameter selected Qtr & Year set Default value of start & End Date

```
=DateSerial(Parameters!Year.Value), (3*Parameters!Qtr.Value)-2, 1)  --First day of Quarter
=DateAdd("d",-1,DateAdd("q",1,Parameters!Year.Value, (3*Parameters!Qtr.Value)-2, 1))) --Last day of quarter
```

Doing this no need to do any validation bcz its always get the correct Date Difference.

Other Reference

```
First day of current quarter

=DateSerial(Year(Now()), (3*DatePart("q",Now()))-2, 1)

Last day of current quarter

=DateAdd("d",-1,DateAdd("q",1,DateSerial(Year(Now()), (3*DatePart("q",Now()))-2, 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you! The second ways fits me best.